# RamMap processes private memory doesn't add up

Tags: windows, windows-10, memory, memory-leaks

The summary tab shows 27 GB used:
[image]
But processes don't add up to this amount:
[image]

What's using memory?

Comment: But they absolutely do add up to (almost) 27 GB, even though not all are visible in the screenshot. Even those 200 MB-ish processes do add up to multiple gigabytes.

Comment: @DanielB They add up to ~21 GB